# Unsubscribed from switchmap inner observable while keeping source observable active - Angular / RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to do an http call when the value of an input changes. Something like this:

```
this.formControl.valueChanges
    .pipe(
       switchMap(text => this.service.getRequest(text))
    ).subsscribe()
```

Then I also want the ability to unsubscribe from the inner observable and terminate the request whenever some kind of event triggers, but at the same time keeping the source observable `this.formControl.valueChages` active.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

**EDIT 1:**

I think I was missusing takeUntil but I think I got it working:

```
private _unsub = new Subject<void>();

this.formControl.valueChanges
    .pipe(
       switchMap(text => this.service.getRequest(text).pipe(takeUntil(this._unsub)))
    ).subsscribe()

onClick() {
   this._unsub.next();
   this._unsub.complete();
}
```

Correct me if I'm this isn't the right approach!

Comment: _"whenever some kind of event triggers"_ - what kind of event and where is it triggered from?

Comment: I'm building a chat application and I'm trying to get the preview of a link whenever a user types a link in the input. If the user sends a message before the http request to get the preview link metadata completes I want to terminate the request and unsubscribing. At the same time I want to keep listening for future input changes

Comment: It seems like sending the message would clear the input which would send an empty string through your valueChanges. Meaning that your inner observable would automatically be replaced (cancelled as you mentioned).

Comment: If `this.service.getRequest(text)` is an http request then after receiving a value stream completes.
And I would place `takeUntil` next to `switchMap`